# MYSQL UPDATE and SET statements in PHP (500 error response)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, set

I'm a newb, so thanks in advance for bearing with me. That being said, I'm trying to update a table in my database and failing. I received a few NULL responses, adjusted a few things, and most recently got a few 500 internal server errors, which typically seem to be related to invalid PHP... any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_POST['room']) {

$room_current = $conn->query('SELECT `Room_Availability` FROM Room_Status WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"');

if (!$room_current) {
    die('ERROR: '.$conn->error);
}

$room_current = $room_current->fetch_assoc();

if ($room_current['Room_Availability'] == `OUT`); {
    $room_set = $conn->query('UPDATE `Room_Status` SET `Room_Availability`= `IN` WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"');

    if (!$room_set); {
        die('ERROR: '.$conn->error);
    }
}

var_dump($room_set);

?>
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: `... == \`OUT\``? You should be using quotes(single or double) instead of backticks, like this: `... == "OUT"`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 3):

This is your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `Room_Status`
    SET `Room_Availability` = `IN`
    WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"'
```

The backticks around `IN` mean that this is a column reference.  You probably want a string, so use single quotes:

```
UPDATE `Room_Status`
    SET `Room_Availability` = 'IN'
    WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"'
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the

```
$room_set = $conn->query('UPDATE `Room_Status` SET
`Room_Availability`= `IN` WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"');
```

to

```
$room_set = $conn->query('UPDATE `Room_Status` SET
`Room_Availability`= 'IN' WHERE `Room_Name` = "'.$_POST['room'].'"');
```

Comment: Hey guys,  thanks so much. I've made those adjustments and I'm still getting an error. The console suggests that other errors exist in a separate PHP file, so now that I have corrected this issue and I can work on from here. Ty again! I'm teaching myself and that information about the backticks was totally new to me and incredibly useful.